# When were Scrum "ceremonies" renamed "events"?

Tags: scrum, agile

I took a Certified Scrum Master (CSM) course and certification in 2007. Back then, the Sprint Planning, Sprint Review, Sprint Retrospective and Daily Scrum were called *Scrum ceremonies*.

Reading the current Scrum Guide, I see that these are now called *Scrum events*. When was this changed?

Comment: There are certain phrases that instantly indicate that somebody is a CSM, "ceremonies" is one of them. This question highlights an importance in up keeping one's knowledge.

Comment: When downvoting, stackexchange ettiquete suggests leaving a comment explaning why.

Answer (score 5):

I have copies of all of the Scrum Guides. The 2010 version does not use the term "event" or "ceremony", but rather calls them "meetings" and uses the phrase "time-boxes" to refer to any of the things. The 2011 version of the Scrum Guide does use the term "events". Ceremony is a general term that isn't specific to Scrum - without a standard term, it's one that is likely to be familiar to people being trained in Scrum.

Comment: My [collection of Scrum Guides](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1alBmXO9bwvOrnEmLntj02sU39GVGjhjx?usp=sharing) and published changes. (There are often more changes than noted in the revision list.)

Comment: @AlanLarimer Wow. I didn't realize that there were so many unnoted revisions. I'll have to dig through those to see if I can find a better answer to the question.

Comment: @AlanLarimer Even with your additional guide revisions, the earliest reference to "event" I can find is in the July 2011 Scrum Guide. I can't find any use of "ceremony" with a search (but if something is preventing search from working, such as an image or something, I can still flip through real quick to confirm when I have a bit more time).

Comment: Wish I could find that conversation regarding a diff of the 2016-2017 versions.  They're usually not major changes, but the semantics of the guide are deliberate so each change is important.  I found the same results (2011 version) regarding "event" as well.

Comment: @AlanLarimer There is [this thread](https://www.scrum.org/forum/scrum-forum/13380/what-do-you-think-about-revision-changes-scrum-guide-2017) on the Scrum.org forums that point out things missing from the revision history. There may also be a second thread there (if it wasn't merged into that one). Is that what you were looking for?